Using Laravel's `Log::spy` with channels
I have a FormRequest that logs validation error details:
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        Log::channel('logistics')->info('Validation failed. Submitted serials:', [
            'contents' => $this->input('contents'),
        ]);
...

I want to test that this logs correctly, so in a test I'm doing this:
        Log::spy();
        $this->postJson(
            'logistics/delivery',
            [
                'location_id' => $location->uuid,
                'contents'    => [
                    $case1->serial,
                ],
            ]
        )
            ->assertUnprocessable();
        Log::shouldHaveReceived('info')
            ->withArgs(function ($message, $context) use($case1) {
                $this->assertStringContainsString('Validation failed. Submitted serials:', $message);
                $this->assertArrayHasKey('contents', $context);
                $this->assertEquals([$case1->serial], $context['contents']);
                return true;
            });

This fails in the FormRequest because after being mocked with spy, Log::channel('logistics') returns null, I assume because the mocked Log facade contains no channels, but the net result is that it only fails when testing; it works fine normally.
I'm using Log::spy with Log::shouldHaveReceived instead of Log::shouldReceive because there may be other logging calls during the test run, and they create ambiguity that can be avoided with spy.
I also tried spying on the channel specifically, using Log::channel('logistics')->spy();, but that doesn't exist.
If I remove the use of channel() in both code and test, it works fine.
How should I test this?

I think you have to Log::shouldHaveReceived('channel'),  because if you don't do so, there is no call (from when the spy is set), to identify that you called info as it is after channel

It's not that as it crashes before it gets to that point. Fundamentally, Log::channel() (in the code being tested, not the test itself) doesn't work if you have previously called Log::spy().

Oh, you are right, I totally forgot about it, sorry. I see that this is the code being executed for channel(), and the parsing is null unless you have set the driver (you did), what is the final error, because the code is also saying that it will set the emergency logger, so info should still work. Could you add the error please?

My API endpoint returns a 500, and the internal error is Call to a member function info() on null; I can only get to see this using a debugger, because after the call to spy, normal logging stops working! I added one other detail: if I remove the channel() call from both code and test, it works (i.e. spying on the default logger works).
